# Multiple if-else Vs for loop

Tags: iphone, objective-c, performance

While going through parsing a xml doc i have used multiple if-else to parse the data tag wise. I can do the same with for loop also. But i am confused about which to use so as the performance will increase. Which will be the faster one ?

```
//Parsing with If-Else

if(element.name isEqualToString:@"String1") {
object.id = [element.value intValue];
}
if(element.name isEqualToString:@"String2") {
object.name = element.value;
}
if(element.name isEqualToString:@"String3") {
object.address = element.value;
}
.....

// OR Parsing with for loop

for(NSString * str in NSArray) {
[dict setObject:element.value forKey:element.name];// This will add parsing element in dict
}

//Use the dictionary to show data later
```

Comment: Not sure which one is faster for performance, but in the case of if-else you should be using `if else if` statements for more performance since once it has an answer it will skip the other statements. ie - if (test) { do stuff } else if (other stuff) { do other stuff }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really as much a question about representation as it is about code structure.  An object with named properties strongly suggests an if-elseif structure, and a dictionary strongly suggests a loop.

XML (and all of it's kin) are perfectly paired with name-value representation.  Tags are names and tag bodies are values.

The dictionary is the way to go, and therefore so is the loop.  This is the choice made by the NS parser as well as any third party I can think of.

Answer (score 1):

Dictionary lookup can be faster as it uses key hashes. That said, you should always profile the code before attempting to optimize it.

Personally, I like the dictionary approach because it is less mundane code. Moreover, you can easily map element names to dictionary keys of interest:

```
NSDictionary *keySubstitutions = { @"String1" : @"id", @"String2" : @"name", ... };

for(NSXMLElement * element in elements) {
    id key = keySubstitutions[element.name];
    if (key)
        dict[key] = element.value;
    // else the element name is not supported
}
```